# How to load text with special chars from file .properties and use it to sign the app

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to load my user, alias and password data saved in JSON to string witch charset UTF-8 to be able sing in my app.

Here is the list what I have tried before:

```
releasePlay {
    storeFile file("android_market_key")
    storePassword = "xxx"
    keyAlias = "yyy"
    keyPassword = "zzz"
}
```

It was working but without special chars like like łóżćź...
So I created a file, wrote a password and I used that configuration::

```
releasePlay {
    storeFile file("android_market_key")
    storePassword = "xxx"
    keyAlias = file('password.properties').getText('UTF-8')
    keyPassword = "zzz"
}
```

It was working but it was not enough to be secure. Another way was to use this:

```
releasePlay {
    storeFile file("android_market_key")

    def console = System.console()
    if (console != null) {
        storePassword = System.console().readLine("\n\$ Enter keystore password: ")
        keyAlias System.console().readLine("\n\$ Enter key alias: ")
        keyPassword = System.console().readLine("\n\$ Enter key password: ")
    }
}
```

It was working but it was also to slow to write all data manually every time.

I've decided to use external json lib for reading all datas from file and by parsing values use them as signing params. However I stuck I don't know how to use this external library in singnin clousure. Whole problem is around releasePlay clousure. Here is my code:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
            classpath 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:14'
        buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "x.xxxxxxxxx.rorlistservers"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 20
            versionCode 7
            versionName "1.5"
        }
    
        signingConfigs {
    
            releasePlay {
    
                def versionPropsF = file('sign.properties').getText('UTF-8')
!Error! >>>     def versionProps = new ObjectMapper().readValue(versionPropsF, HashMap.class);
                storeFile file("android_market_key")
                storePassword = versionProps['storePassword']
                keyAlias = versionProps['keyAlias']
                keyPassword = versionProps['keyPassword']
            }
    
        }
    
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds true
            abortOnError false
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                //res
            }
    
            release {
                //res
            }
        }
    
        productFlavors {
            play {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.releasePlay
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/" }
        maven { url "http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/" }
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
        compile project(':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator-')
        compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    
    }
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
Error:Could not find org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0.
Required by:
    MyAppName:app:unspecified
```

**tl;dr**

1. I want to load text (saved in json format) from file, pase it to
   hashtable and save it to values like storeFile,storePassword.
2. Fails because I don't know how to do it.
3. I added to dependecies clousure json library but I am still getting erros.
4. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the repo `http://download.crashlytics.com/maven` doesn't have the dependency `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0`. One way to solve this problem is to add the `mavenCentral()` repo. Alternatively, you could parse the JSON using Groovy's `ConfigSlurper` class.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, I used ConfigSlurper:
In build.gradle I wrote:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:14'
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x.xxxxxxxxx.rorlistservers"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.5"
    }

    signingConfigs {

        releasePlay {

            def fileJsonConfig = file('sign.properties').getText('UTF-8')
            def config = new ConfigSlurper('app').parse(fileJsonConfig)
            storeFile file(config.storeFile)
            storePassword = config.storePassword
            keyAlias = config.keyAlias
            keyPassword = config.keyPassword

            println fileJsonConfig
            println config
        }

    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //res
        }

        release {
            //res
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        play {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releasePlay
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/" }
    maven { url "http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/" }
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile project(':libraries:ViewPagerIndicator-')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'

}
```

And the struct of sign.properties was (UTF-8 charset!):

```
environments {
  app {
    storeFile = "android_market_key"
    storePassword ="xx"
    keyAlias = "yy"
    keyPassword = "zz"
  }
}
```